# Script Task - Add existing file as link

Tags: ssis

I've been looking for an answer to this for a bit now but couldn't find anything. I was wondering if it is possible to add an existing file to the project created under the script task in an SSIS package. What I want to be able to do is to add one file called Helper or Utility to the solution and then add that file to all the script tasks for common functions. This is so if I change the class, it gets pushed through to all script tasks.

I know that I can add a reference to a DLL and add it to the GAC. I have tried this and it works. I've also tried adding the file to the projects and that works too.

This is just another solution that I'm trying, just in case I'm not able to deploy the DLL in prod. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar.  I have a Utility.cs file located on my file share that I want to have be my central spot so any SSIS package referencing that class has it without having to explicitly include the file in every package.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need a master copy of your classes, you can copy them from an existing Script Task using the same process below but in reverse.

1. Open the Editor for the Script Task  and on the Property Explorer click on the Project File (the st_[Guid] ), in the Properties window you’ll see the Project Folder location. (This location gets recreated every time you edit the script task)
2. In explorer, copy your classes to this folder
3. On the Project Explorer, click on the “Show All Files” icon
4. Right click on your files and add to Project

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular VS functionality for linking files:

1. Right click your script project
2. Add > Existing item...
3. Select files to be included in your project
4. In the bottom right corner of the Open file dialog box you have a drop-down with 2 options: "Add" or "Add As Link" - select the latter one and you are done (see image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can not use relative path after adding pages using Add link. Each user need to correct the path before running the project. The script task uses its own path.it doesn't run from package path which is the problem.